# NFS server service won't stop, client mount timeout?

Tags: nfs, ubuntu-11.04

Client machines were able to connect to our NFS server earlier this afternoon, and everything was running fine. The setup has been working fine for several years. No configuration changes were made on the server.

The NFS server hung with a "too many open files" error, and unable to ssh into it, we shut it down via ACPI. After the NFS server was restarted, all attempts by clients to connect to it hang forever.

Steps taken so far:

**Verify the NFS daemon is running**

```
service nfs-kernel-server status
nfsd running
```

**Restart NFS daemon. This is where I ran into something bizarre**

When I run:

```
service nfs-kernel-server stop
```

It says:

```
 * Stopping NFS kernel daemon                                                                        [ OK ] 
 * Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                                                  [ OK ]
```

Then I run:

```
service nfs-kernel-server status
```

and it says:

```
nfsd running
```

So no idea if it is actually stopping the service or not, since it claims to stop, but then says its still running anyway. Also, running stop multiple times does not produce an error- it just says it `Stopping NFS kernel daemon` each time I run the stop command.

When it is supposedly stopped, `ps aux | grep nfsd` shows:

```
root       761  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr04   0:00 [nfsd4]
root       762  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Apr04   0:00 [nfsd4_callbacks]
root       763  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Apr04   0:00 [nfsd]
root       764  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Apr04   0:00 [nfsd]
root       765  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Apr04   0:00 [nfsd]
root       766  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Apr04   0:00 [nfsd]
root       767  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Apr04   0:00 [nfsd]
root       768  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Apr04   0:00 [nfsd]
root       769  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Apr04   0:00 [nfsd]
```

So it appears that the stop command isn't actually stopping the process.

**Reboot NFS Server again**

Failing that, we rebooted the NFS server using `reboot`. We get the same problem every time we reboot, mount attempts still timeout, and NFS appears to be keep running even when we try to stop it.

**Verify portmap is running**

```
root@nfs:~# service portmap status
portmap start/running, process 540
```

**Stopand restart portmap and NFS**

I went through the motions of:

```
service nfs-kernel-server stop
service portmap stop
service portmap start
service nfs-kernel-server start
```

But since the nfs-kernel-server service doesn't actually stop when you tell it to (see above), it didn't do anything other than restart portmap.